# Keycloak with Angular logins automatically

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have an Angular 9 application. Trying to connect with Keycloak server.
My final goal is to have SSO for 3 applications, with auth-guard on each (access only some pages requires authentication).

Having multiple issues, but let do one at a time.

Using keycloak-angular with keycloak-js.

When I do keycloak.login() (with or without redirectUri) most of the time it goes to keycloak/auth page and comes back authenticated - without waiting for user input.
I did double-check not to save any user data in browser autofill.

I will share more data upon request.

---

Update:

I see in the Keycloak console, that even after logging out, the session is still active.
using:

```
keycloakservice.clearToken();
keycloakservice.logout();
```

Update:

changed logout code to:

```
this.keycloakService.logout().then(() => this.keycloakService.clearToken());
```

The keycloak cookies are removed every time, but the session in keycloak stays about 50% of the times. (see screenshot).
Angular, Keycloak-js and keycloak-angular are updated to the latest version.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What about cookies? For example if there's  a refresh token, it will login automatically.

Comment: the cookies are always removed, but the session in keycloak stays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't have proper logout.

You have to visit your identity provider (Keycloak in this case) OIDC logout endpoint for correct OIDC logout - just navigate whole browser (background AJAX/axios call doesn't work!) to:

```
https://keycloak_host/auth/realms/insert_realm_here/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=<your-app-host/optional-whitelisted-url-where-you-say-goodbye-to-users>
```

That terminates your Keycloak SSO session correctly. `redirect_uri` is optional parameter and it will be nice user experience if you redirect user back to some "good bye" route - it must be whitelisted from the authentication, because user won't have any SSO session/cookie at that time.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I will try that. So why they even added AXAJ logout functionality when it's not working?

Comment: I asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66396544/keycloak-on-angular-not-getting-correct-status-on-load

Comment: @FilipWitkowski it is working as it is designated - but logout() is only for local app session logout.

Comment: Ok, this works. I understand this now, however I wish there would be API call to logout from keycloak admin. I approved your answer. You seem to be experienced with this topic. Can you take a look at my second question? Thanks

Comment: @FilipWitkowski It can't be an API call, because you need to delete session/cookies of IDP in used browser -> so you have the redirect browser to logout endpoint and IDP deletes them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as I am using [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) with angular 12.
The library allows you to get the URL for logout from your STS (Keycloak) by using the method [getEndSessionUrl()](https://nice-hill-002425310.azurestaticapps.net/docs/documentation/public-api#getendsessionurlcustomparams----configid-string) and then you do a [logOut](https://nice-hill-002425310.azurestaticapps.net/docs/documentation/login-logout#logout) and in the subscribe callback you redirect your browser to the Keycloak logout URL which ends your session on the Keycloak server.

The answer by @Jan Garaj is right.